# how to populate ObjectResult from List<>

Tags: c#, entity-framework, testing

In order to test a method that uses a stored procedure, a fake method has been created. This method is to return a list of  ints.

Something like this ...

```
    public virtual ObjectResult<Nullable<int>> available_IDs( ... )
    {
        List<int?> fakeAvailableIDList = new List<int?>();
        fakeAvailableIDList.Add(1);
        fakeAvailableIDList.Add(2);
        fakeAvailableIDList.Add(3);

        ObjectResult<Nullable<int>> result = fakeAvailableIDList.All(m => m > 0);
        return result;
    }
```

which fails with

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectResult<int?>'
```

tried (amoungst other things)

```
ObjectResult<Nullable<int>> result = fakeAvailableIDList.All(m => m > 0);
```

which gives

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<int?>' to 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectResult<int?>'
```

how can I get a List<> into ObjectResult ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line

```
fakeAvailableIDList.All(m => m > 0);
```

returns a boolean because `.All` returns `True` or `False` depending on whether or not all elements in the collection meet the specified condition.

So, a variable of type `ObjectResult` can't be set to a variable of type `Bool`.

The `ObjectResult` and `ObjectResult<T>` types have hidden constructors, which means you can't create instances at will. Also, the `ObjectResult<T>` type is sealed, which means it can't be extended. So, you might be out of luck if you're looking for an easy way to create an `ObjectResult` from an `Enumerable`.

The easiest thing to do, I think, would be to change the type used by the method you're trying to test. So, if that method has the signature:

```
void Foo(ObjectResult<int?> result);
```

Change it to:

```
void Foo(IEnumerable<int?> result);
```

That will allow you to create a fake collection with which the method can be tested, and you'll still be able to pass the method an `ObjectContext<int?>` type because `ObjectContext<int?>` extends `IEnumerable<int?>`.

Comment: Thankyou Ken, pleased I'm not missing something obvious.  The method is within a fake for entity framework context so the function signature cannot altered.  Might use Moles to mock it.

Comment: As of EF 6.1.3, constructor for ObjectResult<T> is protected, and class is no longer sealed. That allows for inheritance, and you can create MyObjectResult<T>:ObjectResult<T>, where a List<T> can be passed in, and GetEnumerator can be overridden eg. _list.GetEnumerator, and the derived class can be used wherever the base ObjectResult<T> is returned.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this has already been answered, but a solution I have come up with is to mock the specific Linq extension off of `ObjectResult<T>`.

For example:

```
Mock.Get(PortalEntitiesMock).Setup(m => m.ExecuteSqlQuery(It.Is<String>(x => x.ToUpper().StartsWith("SELECT"))).FirstOrDefault()).Returns<string>(p=>p).Verifiable();
```

So, you can mock individual items on a O`bjectResult<T>` object if not the actual `ObjectResult<T>`.